# Why is my method using lookup table so slow compared to brute force method?

Tags: python, performance, time

This question is about Euler [Problem 21](https://projecteuler.net/problem=21):

The basic algorithm is setting up a lookup table `d_value`, which will store the `number: d(number)` as we go from `2` to `10000`.

Then in order to call `d()` function as few times as possible.

Whenever we have a number, we will check if this number already exists in the `d_value.keys()`.

If not then we'll add this key with value of `d(number)`.

The same goes for `d_number`.

Then we compare if it suits the definition, if so, we add the `number` to the `amicable_number_sum`.

Then next `number`.

My code is like this :

```
from math import sqrt

def d(number):
    sum = 1
    for foo in range(2, int(sqrt(number)) + 1):
        if number % foo == 0:
            sum += foo
            sum += number/foo
    return sum


d_value = {}
amicable_number_sum = 0

for number in range(2, 10000):
    if not number in d_value.keys():
        d_value[number] = d(number)
    if not d_value[number] in d_value.keys():
        d_value[d_value[number]] = d(d_value[number])
    if number == d_value[d_value[number]] and not number == d_value[number]:
        amicable_number_sum += number

print amicable_number_sum
```

This code would take 2.14s to complete.

THEN there is the brute force method that I was trying to "avoid", which takes 0.147s to complete. 
:(

It calls function `d()` as long as we need to know the `d()` of one number.

```
from math import sqrt


def d(number):
    sum = 1
    for foo in range(2, int(sqrt(number)) + 1):
        if number % foo == 0:
            sum += foo
            sum += number/foo
    return sum


amicable_number_sum = 0

for number in range(2, 10000):
    d_value = d(number)
    if d(d_value) == number and not number == d_value:
        amicable_number_sum += number

print amicable_number_sum
```

So which part of my code that's taking up all the time?

My guess was the two `if` check with dictionary keys.

But since I got no means to check the time consumption within code(is there one?), I'd like to hear about your take on this.

Comment: Try to describe the algorithm instead of code if this is an algorithm question.

Comment: @simonzack thanks for the suggestion. I have moved the algorithm to the beginning part of the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time is consumed in dictionary key lookups, specifically the lines:

```
if not number in d_value.keys():
```

and

```
if not d_value[number] in d_value.keys():
```

Calling `keys()` is not necessary - a simple lookup on  the dictionary will suffice, i.e. change those lines to:

```
if not number in d_value:
```

and

```
if not d_value[number] in d_value:
```

You should now see faster performance for your optimised algorithm.

You can determine this by using the [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#the-python-profilers) module on this slightly reorganised code:

```
from math import sqrt

def d(number):
    sum = 1
    for foo in range(2, int(sqrt(number)) + 1):
        if number % foo == 0:
            sum += foo
            sum += number/foo
    return sum


def runit():
    d_value = {}
    amicable_number_sum = 0

    for number in range(2, 10000):
        if not number in d_value.keys():
            d_value[number] = d(number)
        if not d_value[number] in d_value.keys():
            d_value[d_value[number]] = d(d_value[number])
        if number == d_value[d_value[number]] and not number == d_value[number]:
            amicable_number_sum += number
    print amicable_number_sum

import cProfile
cProfile.run('runit()')
```

**Output**:

```
         51632 function calls in 2.366 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.366    2.366 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    1.711    1.711    2.366    2.366 ams.py:12(runit)
    10544    0.068    0.000    0.079    0.000 ams.py:3(d)
    10544    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {math.sqrt}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
    19996    0.576    0.000    0.576    0.000 {method 'keys' of 'dict' objects}
    10545    0.008    0.000    0.008    0.000 {range}
```

Which shows that a lot of the time is spent in "method 'keys' of 'dict' objects", i.e. the pre-insertion dictionary lookup.

After modification to just use `value in d` the profiling output is:

```
         31636 function calls in 0.109 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.109    0.109 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.010    0.010    0.109    0.109 ams_fixed.py:12(runit)
    10544    0.088    0.000    0.099    0.000 ams_fixed.py:3(d)
    10544    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {math.sqrt}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
    10545    0.009    0.000    0.009    0.000 {range}
```

Comment: Wow.Thanks This definitely is the problem here. Both in 10000 and 100000 case, the optimized algorithm is about 30% faster. So what's the reason? Is it because whenever I call the `keys()`, python will try to iterate through the existing dict to generate a new list with the keys name. However simple lookup is more ...how to put this... built-in and fast?

Comment: Yes, I'd say that's why - time spent generating the list of keys and then performing an `in` operation on the resultant list would be O(n), whereas "native" lookup of the dictionaries keys would be O(1).

Comment: The clouds are cleared XD. Thanks for the introduction of cProfile module, totally what I was hoping to find.